# Binding value to custom radio button in list box item template (WP8)

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, listbox, windows-phone

I have created my own radiobutton to include index property as following:

```
public class IndexedRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    public int Index { get; set; }  
}
```

I am using this custom radio button in a list box:

```
<ListBox Name="myListBox" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" >
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <my:IndexedRadioButton Content="{Binding price}" GroupName="myGroup" IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}" Index="{Binding priceIndex}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Now, I want to fill this list box with values.

Code behind:

```
public MainClass()
    {
        public MainClass()
        {
           InitializeComponent();

           string[] priceList = new string["1","2","3"];
           List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();

           for (int i = 0; i < priceList.Count; i++)
           {
               MyClass listClass = new MyClass()
               {
                   price =  response.priceList[i],
                   priceIndex = i,
                   isChecked = i==0?true:false
               };
               myClassList.Add(listClass);
            }

            myListBox.ItemsSource = myClassList;
        }
        private class MyClass
        {
           public string price {get; set;}
           public int priceIndex {get; set;}
           public bool isChecked { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

When I run the app, I get this error ->>{System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.} (No stack trace info)

What do you think is causing the error? There is no problem when I set some value to Index staticly in XAML `Index="0"` but there is a problem in binding `Index="{Binding priceIndex}"`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow bindings, you have to declare a Dependency Property. Try this:

```
public class IndexedRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Index",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(IndexedRadioButton),
        null);

    public int Index
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(IndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IndexProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

You'll find more info here:

[Dependency properties for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)